# Add styling to defaultValue in textarea in React

Tags: css, reactjs, textarea, styling, autosize

I am using a [Material UI React component](https://mui.com/components/textarea-autosize/) called `TextareaAutosize`:

```
<TextareaAutosize
  minRows={2}
  style={resize: 'none'}
  defaultValue={<span style={{fontSize: "20px", color: "blue"}}>Content Body</span>}
/>
```

Instead of getting Content Body in the `TextareaAutosize` component, I'm getting this as the default value:

[image]

How do I add styling to the defaultValue?

**Edit code on Stack Blitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fnx6we?file=demo.js

**EDIT**: For clarification, I want ONLY the defaultValue to have the styling I applied. When the user starts typing or removes the defaultValue and starts typing, the styling of the defaultValue should NOT be applied.

Comment: Did you try to add the style directly to the component where you wrote ```style={resize: 'none'}``` ?

Comment: I only want to change the defaultValue style and not the style of what the user types in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defaultValue parameter accepts String values only. Use parameter style to define additional styling. Or use jss like styling for components (check [@mui/styles](https://mui.com/styles/basics/)) EDIT: to change styling of the element "on the fly" you will need to use additional variables and functions. Check demo on code on Stack Blitz.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TextareaAutosize from '@mui/material/TextareaAutosize';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  textAreaWithStyle: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    fontSize: '20px',
    color: 'blue',
    resize: 'none',
  },
  textAreaWithoutStyle: {
    resize: 'none',
  },
});

export default function MaxHeightTextarea() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [valueOfInput, setValueOfInput] = useState('Default Text');

  const returnStyleBasedOnInput = () => {
    if (valueOfInput === 'Default Text') {
      return classes.textAreaWithStyle;
    } else {
      return classes.textAreaWithoutStyle;
    }
  };

  const checkIfDefaultValueInTextAreaAndRemooveIt = () => {
    if (valueOfInput === 'Default Text') {
      setValueOfInput('');
    }
  };

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setValueOfInput(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <TextareaAutosize
      maxRows={4}
      className={returnStyleBasedOnInput()}
      value={valueOfInput}
      onChange={onInputChange}
      onClick={checkIfDefaultValueInTextAreaAndRemooveIt}
    />
  );
}
```

Edit code on Stack Blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fnx6we-3vdn7i?file=demo.js

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I only want to change the defaultValue styling and NOT the styling of the entire TextareaAutosize component.

Comment: @penguin by defaultValue you mean just the text inside TextareaAutosize ?

Comment: Yes. Just the "Content Body". When the user starts typing, the styling should be that of the TextareaAutosize, with no fontSize or color styling applied to the defaultValue.

Comment: Just want to clarify. You want TextareaAutosize to have no specific styles, but when user will start to input some text, additional styling should apply?

Comment: No. I want ONLY the defaultValue to have the styling I applied. When the user starts typing or removes the defaultValue and starts typing, the styling of the defaultValue should NOT be applied.

Comment: Edited, let me know if its an effect you looking for.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. This is essentially what I was looking for! I appreciate your time.